# Monitoring File Access on Android

Tags: android

I need to monitor files that are accessed (or tried to access and failed) by a specific program on my Android device. Something like FileMon on PCs.

There are suggestions on the Net to decompile the program, but I'm looking for a more straight way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use standard **android.os.FileObserver**, this Monitors files (using inotify) to fire an event after files are accessed or changed by by any process on the device (including this one). FileObserver is an abstract class; subclasses must implement the event handler onEvent(int, String). Refer to this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html

Simple example here:

```
import android.os.FileObserver;   
import android.util.Log;   


    /**  
     * SD Card file monitor  
     * 
     */  
public class SDCardListener extends FileObserver {   

       public SDCardListener(String path) { 
              super(path);   
       }   

       @Override  
       public void onEvent(int event, String path) {          
              switch(event) {   
                     case FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS:   
                            Log.d("all", "path:"+ path);   
                            break;   
                     case FileObserver.CREATE:   
                            Log.d("Create", "path:"+ path);   
                            break;   
              }   
      }   
}
```

---

```
SDCardListener listener = new SDCardListener("YOURDIRPATH");   

//Start monitoring   
listener.startWatching();

// You can try to access the directory here 

//Stop monitoring   
listener.stopWatching();
```

One thing you should bare in mind is that you should keep a valid reference to the file observer object to prevent it from GC.